# How it comes out?

Tags: analysis

i am reading a book about wavelet, and in it i find the following computation i feel confused,
$$|f(x)|\le(\int m(x,y)^{2})^{1/2}||f||_{2}  
        =(\sum_{k}|\varphi(x-k)|^{2})^{1/2}||f||_{2}$$.
where $$m(x,y)=\sum_{k}\varphi(x-k)\bar{\varphi}(y-k)$$,and $$||\varphi(y-k)||_{2}=1$$.
It said the last equality comes frome the orthonormality of $$\varphi(y-k)$$,but why? i cann't see how, don't we need use Schwartz inequality?
 Thank u very much, if there is somewhere u think i dont discribe clear,let me know.

Comment: Using $k$ to denote both a function and an index is unwise.

Comment: thank u. then it's also unwise in the book.

Comment: but how the equality comes?